# Port Forwarding Home Server on Raspberry Pi - Connection Issues

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a Netgear router set to port forward on port 80.

I have a node web server running on a raspberry pi on port 80.

When I am connected to my local network, I can hit my web server in the browser, using http://mywanip

However, when I'm not connected to my home network, I get no connection.

Canyouseeme.org testing port 80, I'm getting 'connection timed out'.

This tells me that the port forwarding is working only for requests from within the network.

What is preventing me from connecting to my home server? What steps could I take to find the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can connect via private_ip:80 from another device inside the network, it means that the port is open on the server and the listening process is accepting requests. If you are connecting to public_ip:80 from inside the network and it is working, it is probably NAT reflection. That is usually a good sign though if that works, as it means the router is aware of the IP that port should go to. If you connect to public_ip:80 from outside and it fails, there might be something blocking it. Make sure your ISP allows you to have a server, many block that port on residential circuits.

Comment: Confirmed, I am able to access port 3000 from outside the network, but not port 80. ISP is blocking port 80.